# Intermittent vibration at various speeds

Tags: tires, suspension, vibration

As the title suggests, my new-to-me 2018 Audi A4 vibrates/shudders at speeds ranging from 30-80 MPH. When test driving the vehicle off the lot, I suspected imbalanced tires however, the shop owner rebalanced them for me yet the vibration was still there. It is weird, sometimes the car shakes like a curbed wheel yet other times it is perfectly still. I took this issue to my Audi dealer and the technician and service advisor could not feel anything. I reluctantly agreed thinking it was probably just me but I have driven enough vehicles and worked on enough to know it is not smooth. I also notice the vehicle very gently pulls to the right while driving. I am baffled as to what this may be. Have driven the car 4k miles and it only seems to have gotten worse.

Also, the passenger front tire has a lump on the sidewall. However I do not think that is the cause.

Comment: It could be one of the tires (maybe even the one with a "lump") has slipped a belt. This can cause an out of round situation which would cause vibration at certain speeds. Other than getting a new set of tires, I don't know what else to tell you. You could also check the wheels to ensure they are true.

Comment: #1: This sounds like a suspension problem. It shudders and pulls. Most suspension problems are easily diagnosed by a competent mechanic. #2: It could also be a wheel problem. Vibrations at higher speeds can be from the wheels. A lump on the sidewalk is a big concern. Both of these areas need addressed.

Comment: Did you buy this car from the dealer that balanced the wheels and also told you they couldn't detect the problem?

Comment: @FDryer no, car was bought at a reputable shop, and the diagnosis was made at an Audi dealer, for which they couldnt find the issue. I might just need to get my hands dirty and put the car on a lift